# How to Create a database with a name "insert"

Tags: mysql

I have a customer with a company name "insert"
When i tried to issue the command on

```
mysql> create database insert;
```

I get the below error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert' at line 1
```

Is there some key words that you cannot use as a database names?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT`, `DELETE`, `BEFORE` ,`FROM` etc. are reserved words. MYSQL will not allow to use them as a table name, column name, or other kind of identifier.

**Solution:**

you can user backticks() with these word like:

```
create database `insert` ;
```

OR

skip using these reserved name.

you can refer complete list of reserved keyword [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)